# VBA code to copy and replace a file directly into a .zip folder?

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to make a macro that replaces the vbaProject.bin of a selected Excel workbook (in the "filename.zip/xl" folder), but I'm running into a problem with actually copying the update vbaProject.bin into the zip folder. The first line I tried (now commented out) was:

```
Call fso.CopyFile(tempBinFile, newFileName & "\xl\", True)
```

Which gave me an error that it couldn't find that path, which I assume is because it's within a zip file. So next I tried this line:

```
ShellApp.Namespace(newFileName & "\xl\").CopyHere tempBinFile, 16
```

Which didn't give an error, but also doesn't appear to have actually done anything. Is there a way to directly paste (and replace) into a subfolder of a zip file using VBA? I also tried unzipping the file first and then re-zipping, but I was getting different errors with that, so if anyone has a good solution for doing that instead, that would also be helpful.

```
Sub ReplaceVBABin()

    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim pathName As String
    Dim tempBinFile As String
    Dim xlFolderName As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ShellApp As Object

    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    
    Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    'Select file to patch
    strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
    
    'Rename file to .zip
    newFileName = Replace(strFileName, ".xlsm", ".zip")
    Name strFileName As newFileName
    
    pathName = fso.GetParentFolderName(strFileName) & "\"
    
    'Add copy of embedded vbaProject.bin to directory
    tempBinFile = CreateTempBin(pathName)
    
    'Copy and replace vbaProject.bin in folder
    'Call fso.CopyFile(tempBinFile, newFileName & "\xl\", True)
    ShellApp.Namespace(newFileName & "\xl\").CopyHere tempBinFile, 16
    
    'Delete temp file
    Kill tempBinFile
    
    'Name zip file back to .xlsm
    Name newFileName As strFileName
    
End Sub
```

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm when using Shell to zip/unzip you should use `Variant` types for paths/names. not `String`

Comment: I have a solution using 7-Zip is that is any use ?

Comment: @TimWilliams Good point, although this only seems to work when I'm running in debug mode and can press "Copy and replace" on the system dialog. Any way around that?

Comment: @CDP1802 A 7-Zip solution could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Using the command line options for [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) this shows the 3 steps extract,delete then update that you can adapt as required. It extracts the xl directory to a temporary folder, deletes the xl folder from the workbook and then replaces it with update. I think you can probably dispense with the delete, just extract, replace the vbaProject.bin file and then do update.

```vb
Sub ReplaceVBABin7z()

    Const SevenZipExe = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
    Const tmpDir = "c:\temp\7z\"
    Dim qq As String: qq = Chr(34)  '"
    
    ' check 7-zip exe exists
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.fileexists(SevenZipExe) Then
        MsgBox SevenZipExe & " not found", vbCritical, "7-Zip Not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' create list of commands available
    Dim cmd As String, pid As Double
    'cmd = "cmd /c """ & SevenZipExe & """ >" & tmpDir & "7-Zip_Commands.txt"
    'pid = Shell(cmd, vbHide)
    'MsgBox "Command List see " & tmpDir & "7-Zip_Commands.txt", vbInformation, pid
    
    Dim path As String
    Dim strFileName As String, strBinName As String

    ' select workbook
    path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"
    strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Macro Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
    strFileName = qq & strFileName & qq ' quoted for spaces in filename
       
ext:
    ' extract xl dir and sub dirs into tmpdir
    cmd = qq & SevenZipExe & qq & " x -r -y -o" & qq & tmpDir & qq & " " & _
           strFileName & " xl"
    pid = Shell(cmd, vbHide)
    Debug.Print pid, cmd
    MsgBox "xl directory from " & strFileName & " extracted to " & tmpDir, vbInformation, "EXTRACT pid=" & pid
    'Shell "Taskkill -pid " & pid

del:
    ' delete xl\vbaProject.bin dir and subdir
    strBinName = "xl\vbaProject.bin"
    cmd = qq & SevenZipExe & qq & " d -r " & _
          strFileName & " " & strBinName
    pid = Shell(cmd, vbHide)
    Debug.Print pid, cmd
    MsgBox strBinName & " deleted from " & strFileName, vbInformation, "DELETE pid=" & pid
    'Shell "Taskkill -pid " & pid

upd:
    ' update xl dir and subdir
    cmd = qq & SevenZipExe & qq & " u -r -y -stl " & _
          strFileName & " " & qq & tmpDir & "xl" & qq
    pid = Shell(cmd, vbHide)
    Debug.Print pid, cmd
    MsgBox strFileName & " updated from " & tmpDir, vbInformation, "UPDATE pid=" & pid
    'Shell "Taskkill -pid " & pid

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tested the code, but it doesn't replace the vbaProject.bin. Is it possible to replace the embedded vbaProject.bin inside an xlsm file?